# Excel Power Query conditional Replace Value with Range Look Up

Tags: powerquery

Really struggling and could do with some advice please.

I have an input table in my Excel (2016) worksheet as follows;

[image]

I also have a user-defined value in the spreadsheet as follows;

[image]

The user updates the highlighted value based on the needs of the analysis. The highlighted cell has been named 'NTValue' in the worksheet.

In my query, I have already introduced a function named "GetValue" to get the value in the cell named "NTValue". This function is;

(rangeName) =>
Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name=rangeName]}[Content]{0}[Column1]

This function runs successfully on its own. If I use GetValue("NTValue"), I am returned with "0.001".

**I now want to introduce the GetValue function within a ReplaceValue step in my query** i.e. look for all rows where Value1 = "NT" and replace the contents of Value2 with the user-defined NT Value (highlighted in yellow). The target result is as follows;

[image]

However, when I use this query, I am returned with an error..

**Replace Value Query**

= Table.ReplaceValue(#"Table5", each [Value2], each if [Value1] = "NT" then GetValue("NTValue") else [Value2],Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"Value2"})

**Error**

Formula.Firewall: Query 'New Table' (step 'Replaced Value') references other queries or steps, so it may not directly access a data source. Please rebuild this data combination.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please edit your question to provide enough information (as text that can be pasted) so we can easily reproduce your issue.  Might be useful to read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem with the information you have provided. Seems to work OK here.  Maybe [this](https://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2015/03/11/power-query-errors-please-rebuild-this-data-combination/) will give you some clues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Formula Firewall error is related to Power Query settings.

You should adjust your privacy levels.

[image]